# Find documents by specific hour on MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I got documents in my collection with `createdDate` which is an ISO date. I want to find documents by `createdDate` with a certain hour, lets say `07:00:00`. Is there a way I can do that? I also want to set it to a certain hour, lets say `02:00:00`. I've looked around, but I haven't found a solution. Thank you!

dates look like this:
`2023-07-13 04:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Your date already has timezone built in (the Z at the end). Not sure what you mean by "find documents by pacific hour" - are you referring to PST/PDT? If so: since you're storing all your dates as UTC (which is a Good Thing), you can then convert your local (PST/PDT) time to UTC, before searching. That aside: Please edit to show an actual snippet of sample data, along with the query you wrote, issues you're having, etc. Right now, it's just a high level requirement.

Comment: Sorry auto correct changed the title. I mean SPECIFIC time. For example, I want to find a document that was created at 07:00:00. I need to edit the title

Comment: MongoDB has several [Date Expression Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expression-operators) that should be helpful for your needs.  Do you have a specific question about trying to use any of them in a [query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) or [update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents/)?

Comment: @JLo - good to know on "specific". That said: You still need to show what you've done, along with the issue you're having. Please edit to include your query etc as I mentioned in my other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [{ $hour: "$createdDate" }, 7] } })
```

or

```
db.collection.find(
   { $expr: { $eq: [
      { $dateToString: { date: "$createdDate", format: '%H:%M:%S' } }, 
      '07:00:00'
   ] } }
)
```

Comment: This answer works great to find documents. When I try to $set to different hour, I get errors. How would I go by changing the hour to 02?
This is my query that doesn't work:

    db.getCollection().aggregate([
    {$match : { $expr: { $eq: [{ $dateToString: { date: "$createdDate", format: '%H:%M:%S' } }, '07:00:00'] } }},
    {$set : {[$dateToString: { date: "$createdDate", format: '%H:%M:%S' }, '00:00:00']}}
])

Comment: What do you like to achieve? Your query does not make any sense.

Comment: I need to update the time on some documents which have createdDate at 00:00:00. That was the old way of saving createdDate and it is causing issues for us. We are now saving it as 04:00:00. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please open a new question for it. Just a note, `$dateToString` returns a **string**, it does not update any `Date` object.